# passing object data between viewcontrollers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm learning how to pass object data between viewcontrollers, and my source is:

firstly the class which represents the objects Flyer

```js
class Flyer{

  var title: String!
  var desc: String!
  var imageUrl: String!

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
    title    = dictionary["title"] as? String
    desc     = dictionary["desc"] as? String
    imageUrl = dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String
  }

}
```

now the mainViewController class:

```js
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!

  let apiClient = ApiClient()

  var flyers: [Flyer]!

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    apiClient.mainService.getList() { flyers, error in
      if flyers != nil {
        self.flyers = flyers
        self.tableview.reloadData()
      } else {
        print("error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.flyers?.count ?? 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainObjectCell") as! MainTableViewCell
    cell.mainObject = self.flyers?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
      let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailMainViewController
      if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! MainTableViewCell) {
        detailViewController.detailString = self.flyers?[indexPath.row]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the output of this class is an error, **ambiguous use of tableview(_:numbersOfRowsInSection:)** in the let indexPath

the detailViewController class:

```js
class DetailMainViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var detailMainLabel: UILabel!

  var detailString: String?

  var receivedCellIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        detailMainLabel.text = detailString
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to solve the error in the mainViewController class and how to pass the desc property of the flyer object to the detailViewController and show it in the label field

Comment: Change your `tableview` name with `tableView` and also update Outlet for it. Or try with any other name.

Comment: You mention the error you're receiving in numberOfRowsInSection. Is this the only problem, or are you receiving another error related to the passing of data from one view to another?

Comment: after to solve the error with Dharmesh solution, I can send the object data adding .desc to the call **detailViewController.detailString = self.flyers?[indexPath.row].desc** now the source works perfectly